# How to count values in one column based on another in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a table tracking an employees leave at a business. It has the reason for leave, leave type, total days and day range. For this, only the type and total days matter.

I want to be able to see a brief summary, in numbers, of how many of each of the leave types this employee has used. I've attached a sample of the data below as a photo and raw table. For example, this employee has taken 7 days as LSL, so in the coloured table on the right I'd like a way for Excel to count this for me and display 7 in the box.

[Image of the table in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyW4n.png) - also shown below for convenience

| Leave Type | Leave Days |
| --- | --- |
| A/L | 3 |
| A/L | 1 |
| A/L | 1 |
| A/L | 2 |
| A/L | 3 |
| A/L | 3 |
| DIL | 1 |
| A/L | 2 |
| A/L | 9 |
| A/L | 1 |
| A/L | 3 |
| DIL | 1 |
| LSL | 4 |
| DIL | 1 |
| DIL | 1 |
| A/L | 2 |
| SICK | 4 |
| A/L | 1 |
| DIL | 5 |
| DIL | 1 |
| LSL | 3 |

I have tried using some VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP but can never seem to get it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty textbook example of [sumif](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

Put this in your worksheet in `H3` and drag down `=Sumif(B:B,G3,C:C)`

If you wanted to get something more dynamic (and fancy), you could drop this formula in cell G3 and it would dynamically update as you had new items in column b.

`=LET(zData,DROP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(B:B,1)),1),HSTACK(zData,SUMIF(B:B,zData,C:C))`)

[image]

Comment: I was just wondering if zData is French for The_Data 

Comment: It is... I used to work for a French company called Imerys... "ZZZTEEEVVVVVVEEEEEE!   ze Budghet doez not reconzile.... we neeeeee ya help immmeeeediaaatleeeee...." (I love you France but you gotta learn the "s" sound!)